# multi-column index has 1 unique column vs single column

Tags: mysql, index

let assume that I have 2 columns

```
comment_id | unique
shop_name  | duplicated
```

which case is batter ?

1- making multi-column index using these 2 columns

2- making single column index using comment_id

which one is batter based on your experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest both,

- Making `comment_id` a `PRIMARY KEY`: which is both `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL`
- If `shop_name` is frequently a part of the query, making `shop_name` it's own index.

Comment: comment_id is foreign key but the id is unique  and I already has primary key.  Anyway I will do as you said. Thanks.

Comment: @JoumanaIssa - Why have `id` if `comment_id` is UNIQUE?

Comment: I used to make id for all tables  you are right it's unnecessary. Thanks.